# React native Linear Gradient

Tags: react-native

Im using react-native-linear-gradient, but i get an error:

```
<View style={styles.slideItemWrap}>
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['#9C7D9A', '#A17990', '#AD779C', '#AD6390']}
                start={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }} end={{ x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }}
                style={styles.gradient}
            >
                <View style={styles.imageWrap}>
                    <Image source={item.image} style={styles.slideItemImage} />
                </View>
            </LinearGradient>
            <Text style={styles.slideItemName}> {item.Name} </Text>
        </View>
```

But i get an error : View config not found for name BVLinearGradient, how i can fix it.

Comment: it relate to not linked package. try linking package for ios again. i recommend you to use pod to link this package.